# Combine vectors of list in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a list contains number of vectors with different length as below:

```
lst <- list(c(1,2), c(1,2), c(4,5,10,11,12,13), c(7,8,9))
lst

[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1]  4  5 10 11 12 13

[[4]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[5]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

how can I combine and remove repeated vectors to be  similar to the list below:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1]  4  5 10 11 12 13

[[3]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

for repeated vectors I can use **unique function**.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to remove all duplicated numbers no matter where they occur or does any vector need to be completely contained inside another vector in order to be removed? one of the current answers handles the first case.

Comment: So, you want the sublists `[1]  10 11 12 13` also removed because these lists are contained in `[1]  4  5 10 11 12 13`?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521122/3521006

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option.  We `unlist` the `list`, get a logical `vector` with `duplicated`, `relist` it to a `list` having the same `skeleton` as the original `list`, subset the 'l1' based on the logical `list` with `Map` and `Filter` out the `list` elements having 0 elements.

```
Filter(length, Map(`[`, l1, relist(!duplicated(unlist(l1)), skeleton = l1)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[2]]
#[1]  4  5 10 11 12 13

#[[3]]
#[1] 7 8 9

#[[4]]
#[1] 14 15

#[[5]]
#[1] 19 20
```

#### data

```
l1 <- list(1:2, 1:2, c(4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13), 7:9, 7:9, 10:13, 10:13, 
  c(4, 10, 11, 12, 13), 14:15, 19:20)
```

Comment: @MbrMbr  The OP mentioned in the post about `unique` and it may not work with other duplicate elements.  It also gets 7 `list` elements compared to 5 list elements

Comment: Could you elaborate what your first line of code does?

Comment: @KarstenW.  Updated with some description.

Comment: Thanks, I see it work but I still have to understand it, espescially how `duplicated` is useful in this setting..

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your answer to give a reproducible example. Please let me know if this does not correctly illustrate your problem anymore. If it does, this is trivial:

```
unique(lst)
```

Comment: It will not work and it was already mentioned in the OP' post

Comment: for the example provided `unique` works fine. If it doesn't work in the OP's real problem then we need a different example.

Comment: I already showed the example in my post.  You can check your code with that